# Interpreting shl as multiplication

Tags: assembly

I am debugging this [crackme](http://crackmes.de/users/josamont/crack_serial_in_linux/download). At some point I have `eax=0x61` and `edx=0x4e504700`.

```
0x08048a0b      31c2           xorl %eax, %edx (0x61^0x4e504700=0x4e504761, OK)                                                                                             
0x08048a0d      89d0           movl %edx, %eax                                                                                                                      
0x08048a0f      c1e003         shll $3, %eax (0x4e504761*0x8 = 0x272823b08, but eax becomes 0x72823b08 ???)
```

I interpret `shll $3` as a multiplication by 8. However, I do not know why the result appearing in `eax` in the third line is slightly different from the one I have calculated.

Comment: There are only 32 bits in the `eax` register. Hence, only 8 hexadecimal digits displayed. The 'high' 3 bits are shifted out.

Comment: Thanks. Not examining carrefully the numbers I thought that some bytes get reversed at the front.